# object reference not set to an instance of object exception coming at runtime

Tags: c#

I am getting this error at runtime:
object reference not set to an instance of object

my question is that am i using stringbuilder array correctly here. Because I am new in C#. and i think its the problem with my stringbuilder array. Below is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Collections;


public partial class Testing : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    [WebMethod]
    public static string SendMessage()
    {
        try
        {
            al2c00.ldap ws = new al2c00.ldap();
            Hashtable htPeople = new Hashtable();

            //DataTable dt = ws.GetEmployeeDetailsBy_NTID("650FA25C-9561-430B-B757-835D043EA5E5", "john");

            StringBuilder[] empDetails = new StringBuilder[100];


            string num = "ambreen";
            empDetails[0].Append("amby");
            num = empDetails[0].ToString();

            htPeople.Add("bellempposreport", num);


            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            string output = jss.Serialize(htPeople);
            return output;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message + "-" + ex.StackTrace;
        }
    }
}
```

please reply me what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3):

`empDetails` is currently an array of `StringBuilder`s, and `empDetails[0]` (the first `StringBuilder` in the array) is not instantiated, hence the error you're getting.  What you should do is instead of making an array of `StringBuilder`s (unless that's what you intend...), you should just make a single `StringBuilder`.

```
StringBuilder empDetails = new StringBuilder();
```

Then to append you can just do:

```
empDetails.Append("stringhere");
```

Answer (score 2):

This line creates an array of 100 null references:

```
StringBuilder[] empDetails = new StringBuilder[100];
```

If you want to use `empDetails[0]`, you have to assign something to it first:

```
empDetails[0] = new StringBuilder();
```

It's not clear to me why you are creating an array of 100 `StringBuilders` though. Couldn't you just do this?

```
htPeople.Add("bellempposreport", "ambreen");
```

Comment: I think he was just confused on the syntax for initializing the size of the StringBuilder.

Comment: @Ben V: He explicitly mentioned that he wants an array in his question. Looking at his code carefully though, I don't even see a use for StringBuilder at all. He's just adding a string to it and then fetching it back out again.

Comment: Good point, I missed that.  I'm guessing that this code is just a sample and that eventually there will be a loop where he's appending to the stringbuilder and the hashtable.

Comment: @Ben V: Apparently everyone else missed it too, even though he said he is trying to use an array twice in the question. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother assigning this a value:

```
string num = "ambreen";
```

as it's going to be lost when you reassign it.

This:

```
StringBuilder[] empDetails = new StringBuilder[100]; 
//no need for creating an array of string builders.
```

Should be this:

```
StringBuilder empDetails = new StringBuilder();
```

AND

```
empDetails.Append("amby");

string num = empDetails.ToString();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think he might want to be pre-sized to 100

```
StringBuilder empDetails = new StringBuilder(100);
empDetails.Append("stringhere");
```

Answer (score 0):

Only use stringbuilder if you are combining a **large** document of text. If you are just joining a few (<10) items simply using string.Format or just + them together such as

```
string myEmployee = string.Format("First:{0} Last: {1} Middle: {2}", "Stack", "Overflow", "C#");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. My problem solved using below code:

```
        //Creating stringbuilder array for storing key values
        StringBuilder[] empDetails = new StringBuilder[70];

        for (int i = 0; i < empDetails.Length; i++) 
        { 
            empDetails[i] = new StringBuilder(); 
        }
```